# QT Audio Access to Sample Data

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I am looking for a way to get access to the audio samples when using the QT Audio Framework.  I have an QAudioSink set up being fed from a .WAV file (for now), but I cannot figure out out to get a signal to fire when the samples are moving through.

The example I found indicates using a notify() signal from QAudioSink but the signal isn't found.

```
QString Filename = "mysound.wav";

SourceAudio.setFileName(Filename);
SourceAudio.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QAudioFormat audioFormat;
audioFormat.setSampleRate(44100);
audioFormat.setChannelCount(1);
audioFormat.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int16);

pAudioSink = new QAudioSink(audioFormat, this);

connect(pAudioSink, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),
        this,       SLOT(HandleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));

// SIGNAL notify() not found...
connect(pAudioSink, SIGNAL(notify()),
        this,       SLOT(processAudioIn()));

pAudioSink->start(&SourceAudio);
```

Any thoughts on how to do this ?

### Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For future generations searching for this, I was able to get access to the samples by using a QAudioDecoder like so :

```
pAudioDecoder = new QAudioDecoder(this);

connect(pAudioDecoder, SIGNAL(bufferReady()),
        this,          SLOT(AudioBufferReady()));

connect(pAudioDecoder, SIGNAL(finished()),
        this,          SLOT(AudioFinished()));

pAudioDecoder->setSource(Filename);
pAudioDecoder->start();
```